# Python Custom Iterator: Close a file on StopIteration

Tags: python, file-io, iterator

I have written an iterator class that opens a file in it's `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, path):
    self.file = open(path, "r")
```

How do I close that file automatically when the iteration is finished?

Complete class:

```
class Parse(object):
    """A generator that iterates through a CC-CEDICT formatted file, returning
   a tuple of parsed results (Traditional, Simplified, Pinyin, English)"""
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.file = open(path, "r")

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __is_comment(self, line):
        return line.startswith("#")

    def next(self):
        #This block ignores comments.
        line = self.file.readline()
        while line and self.__is_comment(line):
            line = self.file.readline()

        if line:
            working = line.rstrip().split(" ")
            trad, simp = working[0], working[1]
            working = " ".join(working[2:]).split("]")
            pinyin = working[0][1:]
            english = working[1][1:]
            return trad, simp, pinyin, english

        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

Comment: Can you share the iteration part? Do you use a `.next()` or `.__next__()` method or is `__iter__` a generator method?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll share the whole thing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A better way to write the whole thing would be to keep the opening and the iteration in one place:

```
class Parse(object):
    """A generator that iterates through a CC-CEDICT formatted file, returning
    a tuple of parsed results (Traditional, Simplified, Pinyin, English)"""
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __is_comment(self, line):
        return line.startswith("#")

    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.path) as f:
            for line in f:
                if self.__is_comment(line):
                    continue

                working = line.rstrip().split(" ")
                trad, simp = working[0], working[1]
                working = " ".join(working[2:]).split("]")
                pinyin = working[0][1:]
                english = working[1][1:]
                yield trad, simp, pinyin, english
```

This will wait to open the file until you really need it, and will automatically close it when done.  It's also less code.

If you really want to get into the "generators are awesome!" mindset:

```
def skip_comments(f):
    for line in f:
        if not.startswith('#'):
            yield line

...

    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.path) as f:
            for line in skip_comments(f):
                working = ....
```

Comment: And when the generator method goes out of scope, it is cleaned up automatically, the file is closed, and all is happy and dandy!

Comment: `__iter__` as generator is really the best way to go.

Comment: Only drawback: You need to call `iter()` on it if you want to access the `.next()` method. Small one, probably not an issue for the OP.

Comment: On the plus side, this takes advantage of the read-ahead buffer used by the file iterator. It'll be just that little bit faster.

Comment: beautiful.. I went for the second option

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly close it as soon as `StopIteration` is raised. In this case, simply call `.close()` when you raise `StopIteration` yourself.

```
def next(self):
    #This block ignores comments.
    line = self.file.readline()
    while line and self.__is_comment(line):
        line = self.file.readline()

    if line:
        working = line.rstrip().split(" ")
        trad, simp = working[0], working[1]
        working = " ".join(working[2:]).split("]")
        pinyin = working[0][1:]
        english = working[1][1:]
        return trad, simp, pinyin, english

    else:
        self.file.close()
        raise StopIteration()
```

Since no other code in your `.next()` method could trigger a `StopIteration` this suffices.

If you *did* use `next()` on another iterator inside your own `.next()` you'd have to catch `StopIteration` with an `except StopIteration:` handler and reraise the exception.

This *only* handles the `StopIteration` case. If you want to handle other situations (not exhausting the iterator) you'll need to handle that situation separately. Making your class a [Context Manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) *as well* could help with that. Users of your iterator would then use the object in a `with` statement before iterating over it, and when the `with` suite is exited the file could be closed regardless. You may want to mark your iterator as 'done' as well in that case:

```
_closed = False

def next(self):
    if self._closed:
        raise StopIteration

    line = self.file.readline()
    while line and self.__is_comment(line):
        line = self.file.readline()

    if line:
        working = line.rstrip().split(" ")
        trad, simp = working[0], working[1]
        working = " ".join(working[2:]).split("]")
        pinyin = working[0][1:]
        english = working[1][1:]
        return trad, simp, pinyin, english

    else:
        self.file.close()
        self._closed = True
        raise StopIteration()  

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, type_, value, tb):
    self.file.close()  # multiple calls to .close() are fine
    self._closed = True
```

Comment: So what happens when I break an iteration from main, wouldn't the else  never be reached?

Comment: @trideceth12: at that point your iterator would never raise `StopIteration`. If you want to catch that situation, make your class a Context Manager *as well*.